# Codeigniter POST data name

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, post

I have a problem with post data variable names for example i might get this type of input:

```
<input type="number" name="amount[BKP1P+NC10A]" />
```

Which in theory there is nothing wrong with the array element name and when i am not in codeigniter  i receive the array name and access it as usual but strange is when i am using the `$this->input->post()` or even when i access the data directly from `$_POST` the array element name is removed and instead i get an enumerative array.

For example in normal post (without codeigniter) i get:

```
 array(1) {
  ["amount"]=>
   array(1) {
     ["BKP1P+NC10A"]=>
     string(2) "12"
   }
 }
```

While in codeigniter i get this:

```
array(1) {
  ["amount"]=>
   array(1) {
    [0]=>
     string(2) "12"
  }
}
```

Can anyone tell me whats going on and how i can get the actual name instead of an enumerative array?

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Why in sweet heck do you need the input array name to be `BKP1P+NC10A`. I don't have evidence, but I strongly suspect CodeIgniter `->post()` removes some special characters, perhaps for some potential security exploit or maybe just developer sanity.

Comment: That type of code is a part number and yes it may be used as an element. In codeigniter not only ->post() but even $_POST acts the same and get an enumerative array

Comment: It seems it may not be used as an element in CodeIgniter which is probably why you're getting this behavior. It's likely not documented and you'd have to look into the system code of CodeIgniter to confirm (and fix), but if this array element name is giving you unexpected behavior, it's likely because of the + sign. It's unconventional to use a data key to store data. Instead of trying to use one field to do two things, you should have two fields, the one you have now with a generic key name, and a hidden field with the part number.

Comment: It is in fact the + and i may also have a . in the part number and those two are getting me this behaviour. Though i tried to encode so that + changes to %2B, but still the same effect

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems that the problem as @Goose pointed out is from the core of codeigniter and as i revisited the core input class i found a function _clean_input_keys which contains:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9:_\/|-]+$/i', $str);
```

As you can see + and . are not allowed so i changed it to:

```
preg_match('/^[a-z0-9\+\.:_\/|-]+$/i', $str);
```

Hope this helps anyone!

Comment: I also strongly recommend changing the array key to something generic and if you need to pass the part number down, pass it as a value and not a key. Otherwise you'll be hitting your next problem very soon.

Comment: Already added in my todo list as i hate to tweak in the core files as my thinking is.. that if i need to change something in the core, i am doing something wrong. But for now it will have to work. Thanks for your help